# Xcode build error linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

Build Unity project, add other libraries, Xcode return error. How fix it?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: remove googleplus  framework . clean then run . it will work

Comment: Did you get it work? I am not able to get any solution here, kindly suggest.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you're opening the .xcworkspace and not the .xcproject file in Xcode. Close the project and open .xcworkspace

Comment: solved it for me, showed the error ld: library not found for -IFirebaseAuth

Answer (score 3):

Select your target and go to BuildSettings and Search for Enable Bitcode flag and set it to No.

Comment: I tried this method, but without this framework there are many other errors linker. Flag Bitcode = NO;

Comment: Don't delete this frame work, just set Enable Bitcode flag to No for this product and try it.

Comment: I can show you the error, can you suggest any solution to this problem?

Comment: Try to remove google plus sdk from the project and use cocoapods using "Google" and "Google/SignIn".

Comment: if you have time, could you help me sort out this problem?

Answer (score 1):

just try to clean the build (command + shift + k) and build (command + b) again.

Answer (score 0):

It usually write the error , fix it and then clean build your project :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem disappeared after I removed GoogleMobileAds.framework from the project and added it again by directly dragging and dropping it to the "Linked frameworks and Libraries" section on the "General Tab" under Project Target group. Hope this helps someone with the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change the Target like IOS 5 or 4.It will support the library which you added

Answer (score 0):

[image: screenshot error code]

I also had such a problem, but only Xcode 10.2.1 had a problem, and Xcode 11.1 had no such problems. 
I solved this problem
Select Target, go to BuildSettings and Search for Enable Bitcode flag and set it to No.

[image: screenshot xcode]